# Disabling Visual Studio hosting process on Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, configuration

All instructions to disable Visual Studio hosting process I've found says as follows:

1. Open a project in Visual Studio.
2. On the Project menu, click Properties.
3. Click the Debug tab.
4. Clear the Enable the Visual Studio hosting process check box.

I believe this is for VS 2005 because in my VS 2008 C++ project there is no such tab as "Debug", but rather "Debugging" and there is no check box there for disabling the hosting process.

So my question is, how do I disable the hosting process on VS 2008?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Those instructions are for VS 2008, but they're only for VB / C# projects. As far as I'm aware, VS doesn't use the hosting service for C++ projects.

Comment: The instructions are specifically for C# projects only.  The only way I know to disable it for VB.NET projects is to manually add UseVSHostingProcess set to false in the vbproj file.