# Disabling Visual Studio hosting process on Visual Studio Community 2017

Tags: c#, build-process, visual-studio-2017, vshost.exe

I am trying to disable output of a vshost.exe file to my release folder.
There is a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047643/vshost-exe-file-in-release-folder) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/857096/disabling-visual-studio-hosting-process-on-visual-studio-2008). [This](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185330.aspx) Microsoft doc instruction for 2015, and followed the 2017 rc link and found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-disable-the-hosting-process)

They all mention the **Enable the Visual Studio hosting process** checkbox on the properties **Debug** tab. But this option does not appear in my screen.

I have tried this on the properties pages for **Console Application** and **windows Application** project output types.

Is this feature supported in VS Community 2017 or is there another way to achieve he same result?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This feature seems to be removed in VS 2017. According to [this thread](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-project-system/issues/66) and also [this one](https://vslive.com/Blogs/News-and-Tips/2017/02/Debugging-Visual-Studio-2017-aims-to-speed-up-your-least-favorite-job.aspx). Unfortunately, I haven't found anything from official sources.

So my guess is that maybe you had these files there generated by previous versions (VS2015?). Try deleting all files from bin and obj directories and do a build to see if these files are generated again.

Hope this helps!